# Remote access to Internal memory of Mavic Air is not working

Tags: windows, dji-sdk

After the working mode turned green, the reload button was clicked. It shows:

LaunchFileDataTask get files: SYSTEM_ERROR. Switch Mode or try again.

Tried:

1. Changed the CameraWorkMode to PLAYBACK
2. Changed the MediaFileListLocation to INTERNAL_STORAGE (Since i don't have an SD card, the media files will be stored in the internal storage)
3. Restarted and reconnected the drone to my PC

Lines of codes changed:

```
var msg = new CameraWorkModeMsg
                {
                    value = CameraWorkMode.PLAYBACK
                };
```

and

```
 var fileListTask = MediaTask.FromRequest(new MediaFileListRequest
            {
                count = -1,
                index = 1,
                subType = MediaRequestType.ORIGIN,
                isAllList = true,
                location = MediaFileListLocation.INTERNAL_STORAGE,
            });
```

Expected to see my media files in the playback page but instead, i'm getting this:

LaunchFileDataTask get files: SYSTEM_ERROR. Switch Mode or try again.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same error. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems like the SDK needs a SD card in the drone before it can acces the internal storage. After I put an SD card in the drone the SYSTEM_ERROR disappeared.